# Getting value from struct

Tags: c#, struct

Im trying to get value from the struct and use the value in OverSized to use it in the if statement. but the program doesnt seem like its getting any information from the oversized. by writing on console I can see the value of overSized is true(for example) but that heavy in the third code section doesnt really have any value. Am I calling overSized in a wrong way?
This is my struct for shipping box:

```
public struct ShippingBox
{
    public int Length;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public bool OverSized;
    public ShippingBox(
        int length,
        int width, 
        int height,
        bool overSized)
    {
        this.Length = length;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.OverSized = overSized;
    }
}
```

and this is how I give value to the struct:(typewiseboxes is already defined)

```
     bool overSized = false;
     if (some condition)
                    {
                        overSized = true;
                    }

                int l = 0;
                int w = 0;
                int h = 0;
                if (overSized)
                {
                    l = 100;
                    w = 100;
                    h = 100;
                }
                if (boxTypeWiseNumOfBoxes > 0)
                {
                    typeWiseBoxes.Add(
                        new ShippingBox(
                            l,
                            w,
                            h,
                            overSized));
                }
```

now trying to get the value of oversized with this:

```
ShippingBox specialBox = new ShippingBox();
        var heavy = specialBox.OverSized; //also tried bool heavy
        int tempLength = 0;
        int tempWidth = 0;
        int tempHeight = 0;
        if (heavy)
        {
            tempLength = 101;
            tempWidth = 8;
            tempHeight = 12;
        }
        else if (!heavy)
        {
            tempLength = 77;
            tempWidth = 8;
            tempHeight = 12;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `overSized` variable?

Comment: I fixed my posting its in the second code section I just added

Comment: As hardkoded mentioned.. In your last snippet of code, it seems that you're not actually setting the `OverSized` member anywhere for `specialBox`. In the second code snippet, it only seems like you're only setting `OverSized` in the (what I assume is a) list of `ShippingBox`es called `typeWiseBoxes`. All you're doing in the third section is creating a new `ShippingBox` object with unintialized values and calling `var heavy = specialBox.OverSized;`

Comment: where is the "second section" code placed actually?

Comment: there are 3 code snippets. in second code snippet overSized = false , then on some conditions it set the value to true.on last 7 lines of second code snippet I try to add value of the overSized to shipping box struct which then Im trying to use the value in third code snippet

Comment: @Chris So how can I get the actual value from the overSized in shipping box?

Comment: I mean "where is it placed in your actual code"? You'd better show the relevant part of it and, for instance, see where and how is `typeWiseBoxes` defined

Comment: List<ShippingBox> typeWiseBoxes = new List<ShippingBox>();
then there are lines of condition codes which are irrelevant to this topic.
when I console the results there is a true or false value for overSized. I just dont know how to get the actual value inside of it

Comment: and where is the "third section" code placed with reference to the class `typeWiseBoxes` is?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian You're already getting the value. The problem is that you're not **setting** the value anywhere before trying to get it. For example, do a `Console.WriteLine()` immediately after `ShippingBox specialBox = new ShippingBox();` and output each member variable to the console. For `Length`, `Width`, `Height` and `OverSized` you will see `0`, `0`, `0`, and `false` respectively because all you're doing is creating a new `ShippingBox` and trying to get an **uninitialized** value from it..

Comment: @Chris Understood. Thanks. But now. how can I get the value that is being set in the second snippet

Comment: You would need to follow @DisplayName's answer he just provided and actually assign `specialBox` to one of the objects in your list called `typeWiseBoxes`. I'm not sure if `typeWiseBoxes.Last()` is the element you want but you need to _assign_ `specialBox` to an object instead of creating a brand new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to change:

```
ShippingBox specialBox = new ShippingBox(); // this assigns specialBox an instance of a brand new ShippingBox object
    var heavy = specialBox.OverSized; //heavy will be undefined
    ...
```

to:

```
ShippingBox specialBox = typeWiseBoxes.Last(); // this assigns specialBox the instance of the last ShippingBox object added to typeWiseBoxes List
    var heavy = specialBox.OverSized; // heavy is set to the value of OverSized property of last typeWiseBoxes List element
    ...
```

and thus assigning `specialBox` the *last* element added to the list instead of a *brand new* one

Comment: Thank you. But one more quick question. Is there a way to check if the overSized is true in any of lists in typeWiseBoxes? typeWiseBoxes is a list of lists.

Comment: I tried to upvote you but it says I cant vote for now because of low reputation. I would upvote you if I could. I got downvote on my qestion as well.

Comment: @DisplayName I had upvoted the downvote away shortly after I saw it, because it didn't make any sense as to why this answer received a downvote. You answered the entire question in full and gave the explanation as to why.